# Batch File - Error in FOR / IF statement with numbers and text

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, user-input

These code was working before. I added some additional letters to the "FOR" line and now it's not working.

Goal:  Get user input.  User input can be a number or letter.  Set input as the "SELECTION".

```
:choice1
A. 1-12
B. 1-7
   1.  stuff
   2.  more stuff
   etc to 7
C.  8-10
   8.
    etc to 10
D.  11-12
  11....
  12...

SET /P c= Make a selection or eXit (X)...
CLS
IF /i %c%==X GOTO choice1
IF %A%==1 FOR %%I IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 A B C D) DO (
    IF /i #%c%==#%%I SET SELECTION=%c%
    EXIT /B
    )

IF %A%==2 FOR %%I IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 13 A B C D) DO (
    IF /i #%c%==#%%I SET SELECTION=%c%
    EXIT /B
    )
```

It is not setting SELECTION = %c% on true.  I assume that is not returning TRUE when it should.  This was working before.  I don't understand what changed.  The original line of code was:

```
IF %A%==1 FOR %%I IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 E) DO IF /i #%c%==#%%I SET SELECTION=%c% & EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What changed is that with the original code, `SET SELECTION=%c% & EXIT /B` is executed `IF /i #%c%==#%%I`.

With your modified code, `SET SELECTION=%c%` is executed `IF /i #%c%==#%%I`and the `exit` is executed regardless.

Easily fixed:

```
IF %A%==1 FOR %%I IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 A B C D) DO IF /i #%c%==#%%I (
    SET SELECTION=%c%
    EXIT /B
    )
```

Note however that `selection` would have a trailing space with the original code, but not apparently with the modified code.

Comment: That worked.  Now if i can just get back that time wasted on that mistake.

Comment: Can you tell me why adding `echo %SELECTION% ` after the `SET SELECTION` returns nothing?   It is setting correctly.  I use it later, outside of the IF / FOR / IF and it's right.

Comment: Batch operates by executing one logical line at a time. A logical line is either a physical line or a series of physical lines terminating in parentheses or carets. The logical line is parsed for validity prior to execution and any `%var%` is replaced by the then-current value of that variable. You can display the `current` value of a variable that changes by using `call echo %%var%%` or otherwise access the variable by establishing `delayedexpansion` mode by having already executed a `setlocal delayedexpansion` instruction and then using `!var!` to access the run-time value of the variable.